# gradlew appengineEndpointsInstallClientLibs has error Execution failed for task ':compileJava'. > invalid source release: 1.7

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I can't install the client libs. I always have this error.

```
:tangke-appengine:appengineDownloadSdk
:tangke-appengine:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

What went wrong:

> Execution failed for task ':tangke-appengine:compileJava'.
>   invalid source release: 1.7

my java version is this.

java version "1.7.0_51"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: What JDK do you have configured in android studio?
Project Structure -> SDK Location -> JDK Location

Comment: I have the JDK pointing to 1.7 and still have this error

Answer (score 1):

In the setting search for the Target byte code version.

**Intellij IDEA: Settings > Java Compiler**

Or add the param manually as follows:

```
javac -target 1.7
```